# add widget on the fly

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like to open a main windows and then and add some buttons inside later at runtime.

**EDIT : I update my code to take into account the answer of PRIME (and maybe make the question more precise)**

I wrote this :

'ex_qt.h'

```
#include<QHBoxLayout>
#include<QMainWindow>

class ButtonWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT;

    signals:
        void need_button();
    private slots:
        void start_loop();
        void do_bing();
        void create_button();
    private:
        QVBoxLayout* v_layout;
    public:
        ButtonWindow();
};
```

and 'ex_qt.cpp'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <QtGui>
#include "ex_qt.h"
void ButtonWindow::start_loop()
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        std::chrono::milliseconds timespan(500);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(timespan);
        emit need_button();
    }
}

void ButtonWindow::create_button()
{
    std::cout<<"Creating a new button"<<std::endl;
    QPushButton* button= new QPushButton("auto");
    v_layout->addWidget(button);
    button->show();
}

void ButtonWindow::do_bing() { std::cout<<"BING"<<std::endl; }

ButtonWindow::ButtonWindow():
    QMainWindow()
{
    QWidget* button_widget = new QWidget(this);
    v_layout=new QVBoxLayout();

    QPushButton* button= new QPushButton("click here to begin");
    QPushButton* button2= new QPushButton("make bing");
    v_layout->addWidget(button);
    v_layout->addWidget(button2);

    button_widget->setLayout(v_layout);

    connect( button,SIGNAL( clicked()  ),this, SLOT(start_loop()) );
    connect( button2,SIGNAL( clicked()  ),this, SLOT(do_bing()) );
    connect( this,SIGNAL( need_button()  ),this, SLOT(create_button()) );
    setCentralWidget(button_widget);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    ButtonWindow* bw=new ButtonWindow();
    bw->show();
    app.exec();
    return 42;
}
```

With this code, when clicking on "click here to begnin", I see the main window enlarge 10 times, but the buttons only get visible at the end. Same thing with the "bing" button : if I click on the bing button while the loop is looping, the "BING" is only displayed when the loop is ended.

My aim is to have immediately fully-functional buttons, even while the next button is still not yet created.

How can I achieve my purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this program needs n number of improvements,

But just to start with:

Remove you launch function completely.
Then change your main to:

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        MainWindows* mw=new MainWindows();
        mw->show();
        app.exec();
}
```

This will ensure that your window launches correctly and runs within event loop.
Besides that to add a window after some interval, use a timer object inside your MainWindow class so that after the time intervals it can give you a signal, to the slot ( `newButton` can be that function/slot ) of that signal you can add the widget to the layout.

Besides since you need main window, derive your class from QMainWindow, Use initializer list to initialize your variables.

Also does your program even compile with something like this in your class declaration ?

```
QHBoxLayout* main_layout=new QHBoxLayout;
```

Comment: Yes, it does compile with "-std=c++11". I'm adapting my code to your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the  [processEvents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) function.
Just add

```
qApp->processEvents();
```

after

```
emit need_button();
```

and everything seem to work fine.